# Have other group visitations of the Holy Spirit similar to Acts 4:23-31 been reported in church history?

Tags: church-history, prayer, pneumatology, acts, great-commission

Acts 4:23-31 (ESV):

> 23 When they were released, they went to their friends and reported what the chief priests and the elders had said to them. 24 And when they heard it, **they lifted their voices together to God and said**, “Sovereign Lord, who made the heaven and the earth and the sea and everything in them, 25 who through the mouth of our father David, your servant, said by the Holy Spirit,
>
> “‘Why did the Gentiles rage,
> and the peoples plot in vain?
> 26 The kings of the earth set themselves,
> and the rulers were gathered together,
> against the Lord and against his Anointed’—
>
> 27 for truly in this city there were gathered together against your holy servant Jesus, whom you anointed, both Herod and Pontius Pilate, along with the Gentiles and the peoples of Israel, 28 to do whatever your hand and your plan had predestined to take place. 29 **And now, Lord, look upon their threats and grant to your servants to continue to speak your word with all boldness**, 30 **while you stretch out your hand to heal, and signs and wonders are performed through the name of your holy servant Jesus.”** 31 **And when they had prayed, the place in which they were gathered together was shaken, and they were all filled with the Holy Spirit and continued to speak the word of God with boldness**.

This is an account of a powerful visitation of the Holy Spirit to the early church in response to fervent communal prayer. And what was the outcome? Extraordinary power and boldness for preaching and witnessing -- exactly what the church needs to carry out the great commission.

With such a powerful divine assistance at the church's disposal, it would seem very strange to me if Acts 4:23-31 were an isolated case.

**Question**: Have other group visitations of the Holy Spirit similar to Acts 4:23-31 been reported in church history? If so, what was the aftermath of said visitations? Did revival follow as a result?

Comment: I'm inclined to say this is too broad, that there would be hundreds or thousands of claimed visitations of the Spirit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there have been many more group reports since the Bible was completed in its current form, of the Holy Spirit bringing many to Himself through the outpouring of His spirit.

You can read about Christian revivals around the world, and the wonderful work the Holy Spirit has continued to perform in bringing lost souls into His loving household.

In the Bible we often read about the decline and revival of the Isrealites. This includes the rise and fall of Israel and Judah under good kings and bad kings. Josiah is notable within this biblical narrative as a figure who reinstituted temple worship of Yahweh while destroying pagan worship.

Within modern Church history, church historians have identified and debated the effects of various national revivals within the history of the US and other countries. During the 18th and 19th centuries American society experienced a number of "Awakenings" around the years 1727, 1792, 1830, 1857 and 1882. More recent revivals in the 20th century include those of the 1904–1905 Welsh Revival, 1906 (Azusa Street Revival), 1930s (Balokole), 1970s (Jesus people), 1971 Bario Revival and 1909 Chile Revival which spread in the Americas, Africa, and Asia among Protestants and Catholics.

You can read more about Christian revival here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_revival#:~:text=More%20recent%20revivals%20in%20the%2020th%20century%20include,Americas%2C%20Africa%2C%20and%20Asia%20among%20Protestants%20and%20Catholics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_revival#:%7E:text=More%20recent%20revivals%20in%20the%2020th%20century%20include,Americas%2C%20Africa%2C%20and%20Asia%20among%20Protestants%20and%20Catholics).

On this page, you can read about the 1500s reformation that restored Jesus, the 1900s reformation that restored the Holy Spirit, and the 1994 outpouring of the Holy Spirit on a small church in Toronto led by John and Carol Arnott. This paved the way for the Toronto Outpouring in 1994, which many referred to as the “Father’s Blessing.”

People took this revival home with them and it broke out in their own communities.  On Father’s Day in 1995, a massive revival broke out at Brownsville church in Pensacola. The Father brought healing, joy, and restoration; and it was the starting point of a whole new reformation.

Throughout history, these three key reformations restored Jesus, the Holy Spirit, and the Father back to the church, and resulted in many people finding salvation through Jesus Christ.

The Holy Spirit has also been at work through spiritual ministers/clergy who have performed spiritual healing and deliverance.

You can read about Padre Pio. He performed many miracles in the Catholic Church, and healed many consciences through the confessional.  Father William Bowdern, Father Edward Hughes, and Father Walter Halloran performed medical examinations on Roland Doe at his home and also at the Jesuit hospital near Washington, DC. Eventually, Roland was successfully exorcised and went on to live a normal and successful life in the aerospace industry.

This exorcism lasted for three weeks. Father Bowdern kept detailed journals about the incidents with Roland. These journal entries are in the 1991 book, “Possessed: The True Story of an Exorcism” by Thomas B. Allen. Father Bishop also had a diary. But it was burned by Father Halloran, one of the other priests working on the case.

So, when you read the Bible and see how the Holy Spirit descended upon individuals and groups, brough large numbers into the Body of Christ, and how normal human beings through the power of God healed the sick and drove out devils, you can also read about how this has continued from Bible times through to present day.

Also, many people have been allowed by the Holy Spirit to have NDEs. This includes Satanists, Atheists, Psychologists, Scientists, and Medical Professionals. Many have shared their testimonies of their NDEs and how they came to Jesus as a result of having them. Doctors have written books that you can buy on Amazon, and there are two sites you can visit that study NDE experiences from around the world:

- https://www.iands.org/ndes/nde-stories/iands-nde-accounts.html
- https://nderf.org/

Also, there is also evidence in photographic form that the unholy spirits mentioned in the Bible as devils and demons are still at work on humans and Churches. This evidence also can be used as an explanation of why many Churches have closed down. The photograph itself is taken by a Reverand of his alter in the 1960s, and it has a demon at the alter that he never saw until he got the photograph back from the shop. The BBC and many non-believers tried to debunk the photograph and prove it fake or a double exposure. But the photograph has never been debunked, and to this day remains classified as a genuine photograph of a real demon.

The photograph is known as The Sprectre of Newby Church. The church is located in Newby, North Yorkshire, and you can view the photograph and read about it here:

https://anomalien.com/the-specter-of-newby-church/

I have seen demons of this type when I was unsaved and living a sinful life back in my early 20's. And I know from personal spiritual experience that the figure in the photo is a demon and not a human ghost. They are huge and very scarey.

When I have come under attack, I have always fled to Jesus and He has saved me from them.

And so, hopefully in this answer to your question, you will see that both the Holy Spirit and the Unholy Spirit are still at work on humanity. That outpourings of the Holy Spirit on large groups of people still happens, and that healings and deliverance still take place in the Church today.